# Extracting a file in solaris

Tags: tar, solaris, gzip, gunzip

I'm try to extract a file in solaris to a folder. 
I have tried following combinations but no luck.

`gunzip -c jdk-8u211-solaris-sparcv9.tar.gz > /opt/java/jdk8.2.11`

I'm getting a is directory error.

I have also tried following;

`gzip -dv jdk-8u211-solaris-sparcv9.tar.gz`

Then

`tar -xfv jakarta-tomcat-4.1.29.tar -C /opt/java/jdk8.2.11`

No errors but none of the files got extracted.

Answer (score 0):

With `gunzip -c` you must define the target file, and apparently `/opt/java/jdk8.2.11` is an existing directory (if it weren't, you'd have a tar archive `/opt/java/jdk8.2.11` without the `.tar` extension as a result). I don't have Solaris handy, but I suspect that it would like to have a slash in the end, i.e.

`tar -xfv jakarta-tomcat-4.1.29.tar -C /opt/java/jdk8.2.11/`

(On Ubuntu your command works fine; the resulting `opt/java/jdk8.2.11/jakarta-tomcat-4.1.29/` is created because `jakarta-tomcat-4.1.29.tar` is a tarred directory).